# ASP.NET Core session expires too soon

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that uses session to store some variables. Everything works fine locally in any scenario, but for some reason i am unable to retrieve values from the session at some point (they are null) on an Azure machine.

***Scenario:***

1. Performing login, which redirects to another controller (storing user data in a session)
2. Input some needed data and then redirecting to another controller (also storing some stuff in the session, and retrieving other values)
3. In the Index page, setting some more data to the session. This controller's view is calling a javascript function that calls "**OnScrollEnd**" which is a method implemented by this controller.
4. When the user scrolls down, the same javascript function is called (which calls **OnScrollEnd**)
5. This method tries to retrieve data from the session, but now its null.

(the above scenario demonstrates that essentially session state is working, but at some point it fails to retrieve values)

***Log:***

> 2019-04-23 14:12:34,220 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService
>   [(null)] <(null)> - Authorization was successful. 2019-04-23
>   14:12:34,220 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService
>   [(null)] <(null)> - Authorization was successful. 2019-04-23
>   14:12:34,220 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Executing action method
>   MyWebService.Controllers.AllCardsController.OnScrollEnd (MyWebService)
>   - Validation state: Valid 2019-04-23 14:12:34,220 [29] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Executing action method
>   MyWebService.Controllers.AllCardsController.OnScrollEnd (MyWebService)
>   - Validation state: Valid 2019-04-23 14:12:34,220 [29] INFO  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession [(null)] <(null)> -
>   Accessing expired session, Key:c691acb5-f9ed-5a71-6ebb-f3a0980c4efd
>   2019-04-23 14:12:34,220 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSession [(null)] <(null)> -
>   Accessing expired session, Key:c691acb5-f9ed-5a71-6ebb-f3a0980c4efd
>   2019-04-23 14:12:34,221 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Executed action
>   MyWebService.Controllers.AllCardsController.OnScrollEnd (MyWebService)
>   in 0.7545ms 2019-04-23 14:12:34,221 [29] INFO 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Executed action
>   MyWebService.Controllers.AllCardsController.OnScrollEnd (MyWebService)
>   in 0.7545ms 2019-04-23 14:12:34,223 [29] ERROR
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware [(null)]
>   <(null)> - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the
>   request.

(Exception arises because the value fetched from the session was null)

***Startup configuration:***

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var expiredSessionHours = Configuration.GetValue<int>("SessionExpireHours");
            var expiredSessionMinutes = Configuration.GetValue<int>("SessionExpireMinutes");

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(expiredSessionHours, expiredSessionMinutes, 0);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(expiredSessionHours, expiredSessionMinutes, 0);
            });

            services.AddScoped<IUserAuthentication, AuthenticationService>();
            services.AddTransient<IEncryptionService, EncryptionService>();
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnectionString"))
                    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking), 
                ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.IdleTimeout = new TimeSpan(expiredSessionHours, expiredSessionMinutes, 0);
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked these values in the Debugger? expiredSessionHours and expiredSessionMinutes?

Comment: The Azure is closing connection when it is idle.  So you may need in your client to enable Keep-Alive which will send a empty message to Azure periodically so Azure doesn't close connection.

Comment: @Jon - Yes they are set to 1 hour

Comment: @jdweng How do i do that?

Comment: Not sure what methods you client are using.  Possible setting SetHandlerLifetime.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Show your JS code. You generally need to explicitly pass the cookie back with AJAX, i.e. `withCredentials`.